# Using if in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table which has 2 columns , Branch and role. Basically I want 3rd column which will say 
1) if a branch has  all the three role  (President,Treasurer,Secretary) then 1.
2) If a branch has  2 roles (President,Treasure/secretary) then 2
3) if a branch has 1 role (President/treasurer/secretary) then 3.

How m i going to achieve this. Below is my table structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by counting the rows of the branch, add a new column:

```
    YouGet = 
var br = Branch[Branch]
return 4 - CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Branch);FILTER(Branch;br = Branch[Branch] && (Branch[Role] = "President" || Branch[Role] = "Secretary" || Branch[Role] = "Treasurer")))
```

4 - the row count is to get the result in line with what you ask for.

You can also choose to create a second table with the3 items and a relation between the tables. This gives the advantage that you can extend.

Comment: The problem is there are many other roles, but i want to count only those which has President,Secretary and Treasurer roles.